# Why is applying a 3D translate to a parent div not doing what it should?

Tags: html, css

I have this..

```
 <div class="perspective">
 <div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
 .perspective {
 perspective: 800px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 }

 .parent {
 transform: TranslateZ(200px);
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 }

 .child {
 transform: TranslateZ(200px) rotateY(80deg);
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #ff6060;
 }
```

The problem is that translateZ in the parent div doesn't reslly push the square 200 pixels more in its z-axis. I'm not really sure what it does, but instead of moving the thing it removes the perspective effect and only keeps a flat y-axis rotation.

What I want is for the parent translate to add up to the translate on the child, creating an overall of 400px translateZ value. The reason I'm applying a separate translate to the parent is because I'm working on doing css stairs in which every step is basically five divs wrapped together in one parent that should be pushed in the z-axis for each step.

Comment: Are you using the `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, etc. prefixes for your transforms? If not, you really should, it won't work otherwise.

Comment: sorry I can't do a fiddle, I'm browsing from mobile opera right now. and yeah I am using the prefixes, I just cut them for the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `transform-style: preserve-3d;` on `.parent`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-style-property and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style